# Mongodb aggregation conditionally match array

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a document with an array field named `items`.  This is an optional field and not always set within the document.  So this could either be undefined, empty array, or contain an array of id numbers `[1, 2, 3]`.

What I'm trying to do is return all documents if the `items` array does not exist or is empty, otherwise it should only return those that match a provided `id`.  For example:

```
//This would not match (no documents) returned
id = 4
items = [1,2,3]


//This would match
id = 4
items = []
or
items = [1,2,3,4]
or
items is undefined (does not exist)
```

This is being done in a pipeline aggregation and tried using `$expr` with `$cond` but just not getting there...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: items = [1,2,3,4] would match? You say "array does not exist or is empty" and there is no _id here as well.

Comment: The id value is `4` in the example so this would match this array which contains 4

Answer (score 0):

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      check: {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {
            $or: [
              {
                "$and": [
                  {
                    "$lte": [
                      {
                        "$size": "$items"
                      },
                      1
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    $eq: [
                      {
                        $ifNull: [
                          "$items",
                          0
                        ]
                      },
                      0
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "$eq": [
                  {
                    "$in": [
                      4,
                      "$items"
                    ]
                  },
                  false
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          "then": false,
          "else": true
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      checkFalse: {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {
            "$and": [
              {
                "$gte": [
                  {
                    "$size": "$items"
                  },
                  1
                ]
              },
              
            ]
          },
          "then": true,
          "else": false
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "$expr": {
        "$cond": [
          {
            "$and": [
              {
                "$eq": [
                  "$checkFalse",
                  false
                ]
              },
              {
                "$eq": [
                  "$check",
                  false
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "$or": [
              {
                "$and": [
                  {
                    "$eq": [
                      "$checkFalse",
                      true
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "$eq": [
                      "$check",
                      true
                    ]
                  }
                ],
                
              },
              {
                "$and": [
                  {
                    "$eq": [
                      "$checkFalse",
                      false
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "$eq": [
                      "$check",
                      false
                    ]
                  }
                ],
                
              },
              
            ]
          },
          {
            "$or": [
              {
                "$eq": [
                  "$checkFalse",
                  false
                ]
              },
              {
                "$eq": [
                  "$check",
                  true
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unset": [
      "check",
      "checkFalse"
    ]
  }
])
```

[MONGO PLAYGROUND](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LxD2kNjmTuE)

Comment: This is being done using aggregation framework and this doesn't factor in matching an id in the items when it's not empty.

Comment: ahh, give me a second

Comment: @dzm i just updated, not clear enough, need to change the operator logic

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$ifNull` to wrap the undefined case and empty array case into [].  Then use `$in` to handle the case where the array contains 4. Use `$or` to chain up the 2 criteria.

```js
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $or: [
      {
        $eq: [
          {
            $ifNull: [
              "$items",
              []
            ]
          },
          []
        ]
      },
      {
        $in: [
          4,
          "$items"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/iOMEERFcK-G)

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I ended up going with:

```
      {
        $match: {
          $or: [
            { items: { $exists: false } },
            { items: { $size: 0 } },
            { items: { $in: [$id] } }
          ]
        }
      }
```